# "next" button disabled on Windows 7 installation

Tags: windows, windows-7, vhd

I am trying to install Windows in my virtual hard disk. I have created a VHD, attached it. But when I install Windows 7 on that disk it is giving me the following error:

[image]
The "next" button is disabled for me. How can I install Windows on my VHD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can watch a walkthrough of booting to a VHD [here from the Springboard Series on TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dd758779). Judging from the error you are experiencing, the VHD file may not have been mounted or created properly for the Windows 7 boot loader to work with it.

Most walkthroughs on TechNet also provide instructions for applying a default Windows 7 .wim file to the VHD and editing the Boot Configuration Database (BCD) to ensure that the VHD will boot. Such instructions can be found on TechNet in the article [Walkthrough: Deploy a Virtual Hard Disk for Native Boot](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744338%28v=WS.10%29.aspx).